# MySQL server hang because of too many connection?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have setup a cronjob which request data from API every night and I can receive the results from API within 24 hours as the it has to process data, so I have to provide a call back url.

I make around 1000 request per day. The problem starts when I start receiving response, since I get response one after another, the mysql server hangs and I am not even able to access my server as I get 504 Gateway Time out error.

Is there anyway I can make it handle too many connection from same server and same user in MySQL. I am developing in PHP and using Codeigniter framework.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Even this problem can be due to various reasons but first as per your remarks, check below variables:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_user_connections';
```

If second variable set to less than 1000 then problem can be due to this, but if it is 0 or greater than 1000 then reason can be different and you have to check running queries by this API.

Comment: Yeah, max_user_connections = 0, Codeigniter by default uses persistent mysql connection. I will try using non-persistent one and check if the issue still exists.

Comment: No. I am still facing the issue and have been looking around for solution.

Comment: Share value of these 2 variables and also your query, which result you are getting throug api...

Comment: I have resolved the issue. I had one query which was taking upto 18sec to execute. I forgot to index a column in the table, so now everything is working fine :)